# Can I move an oil tanker?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, estimation

Let's say that I'm standing at the edge of a basin made of concrete. This basin is filled with salt water and a ship floats on the water close to the edge of the basin. The ship is neither anchored nor does it touch the bottom of the basin with its hull.
There are no waves since the basin is closed (let's say the ship was brought in with a crane) and there's no wind.

My question is: How big a ship (in kilograms) can I move if I push against the ship? Assume that my strength is average for a mid-twenty male.

Edit: I'd like to move the ship ten centimeters. In terms of how long I'm willing to push: ten minutes.

Comment: Your question can be answered straightforwardly: 'Yes, you just have to push for a long enough time.'. However realistically I have no idea. Maybe you should say how far do you want to move the ship and for you much time are you ready to stay there pushing if you want a straight answer.

Comment: How wide is the basin, is it similiar to a dry dock? I ask this because I wonder if it was just say 10 or 20 % wider than the ship, as many dry docks are for large ships, would your net force be reduced because of reflection from the far wall, forcing you to *really* push.

Comment: @AcidJazz: Good point! Let's say that the basin is big enough so we can ignore waves reflected from the wall.

Comment: Maybe you could discard the water entirely, and deal with a tanker in orbit around Earth? This allows you to focus entirely on how plausible it is to move extremely heavy things even in an environment with no friction. In fact, most of the operations we do in orbit are quite similar - rather low forces and energies involved, and a whole lot of waiting.

Comment: @Luaan The situation in orbit is rather different: there's no analogue of the wall of the harbour that Matthias could push against.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well, imagine the tanker being in a drydock, then. Sure, you're pushing against a wall, not the ground, which means you can use considerably more force (there's no slipping and you can use a bigger portion of your muscles). Though of course, you'd have to make sure to take the mass of the drydock into account, since you'll impart non-negligible momentum on it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To work out the force needed to move a ship there are two considerations:

1. the mass of the ship
2. the hydrodynamic drag due to the ship's motion through the water

At low velocities the force is likely to be dominated by the mass of the ship because the drag is roughly proportional to velocity. [Newton's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law) tells us that the acceleration of the ship is related to the force you apply by:

$$ a = \frac{F}{m} $$

where $F$ is the force and $m$ is the mass of the ship. The distance the ship moves with time is given by the [SUVAT equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion):

$$ s(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 $$

and substituting for $a$ gives:

$$ s(t) = \tfrac{1}{2}\frac{F}{m}t^2 $$

So you just need to decide what movement you regard as a reasonable minimum, which determines $s$, how long you're willing to wait, which determines $t$, and how much force you can apply, which determines $F$. Then you can calculate the corresponding value of $m$.

Comment: Some numbers: $F$ may be 1,000 newtons. An oil tanker is 50,000 tons or 50 million kg. So F/2m is 1,000 over 100 million = 1 / 100,000. This time t^2 should be 0.1 so t^2 is 10,000, so t is indeed just 100 seconds. A few minutes of intense pressure should be enough to move the oil tanker by 10 cm. Beware: the oil tanker won't stop.

Comment: @LubošMotl The [static coefficient of friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Approximate_coefficients_of_friction) between rubber and concrete is 1.0, so $F = m_{human} g$. $1000 N$ is right assuming a heavy person.

Comment: @LubošMotl it also means that one could **stop** the floating (but moving) ship, right?

Comment: Here is a [**video**](https://youtu.be/-5JFeFPoYFY?t=354) of a man actually moving a 10,000 ton liner by over 5 meters in a few minutes

Comment: Yes, Voitcus, one may stop it by pushing from the other side. ;-)

Comment: I think even at low speeds you need to consider the effort required to displace the water behind the ship. It's easier to push a mass in a vacuum than in water.

Comment: Yes, @LubošMotl, but be careful not to put your hands in between the ship and anything else..

Comment: DJohnM: very important warning! Dear @CarlWitthoft - do you think that the water adds another factor of two because one needs to pump some momentum to the ship, and the same (?) momentum with opposite sign to the water it replaces? I actually doubt this can be right. The most direct thinking is that the pressure on both sides of the ship stays constant, so the force from the water from both directions cancels and it *is* right to calculate it just like if the ship were in the vacuum (on perfect wheels).

Comment: @LubošMotl Not by a factor of two, but you do have to move the water behind the ship out of the way.

Comment: It moves out of the way "automatically" if the ship is moving from one plane to another, as long as there's space for that. Especially at low velocities, there is no obstruction or net force. The only net force that is added would be drag, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)  , but that scales like the second power of the speed and is totally negligible here.

Answer (score 1):

Here in UK we have canals and from experience I know that a barge or a lock gate has to be pushed quite hard for some time before the object begins moving the water from one side of the object to the other.
The barge weighs nothing on water but DISPLACES X tons of water which have to be displaced to make the barge move.
A human of 150 pounds can push and eventually cause a 35,000 pound barge to move but keeping it moving will be extremely tiring - which is why barge horses were invented.
The lock gate doesn't really displace water until the gate starts moving and forces water round the opening edge of the gate.